# Accessibility rules for this and super

Tags: java

I'm having difficulty following the accessibility rules in the Java documentation. I can't find a clear answer to this question.

Suppose you are inside the body of an instance method of a class `C` and that variable `c` has compile time type `C`.

E.g. suppose you have

```
class C {

    <returnType> instanceMethod(...) {
        C c;
        ... 
    }
}
```

Is it true that the set of members (methods or fields) of `C` and its superclasses that you can access for `this` is exactly the same as the set of members you can access for `c`? In other words is it true that `this.member` is allowed exactly when `c.member` is allowed? Or does the fact that it's `this` make a difference?

Does it work for `super`? In other words if the superclass of `C` is `D` and `d` has compile time type `D`, is it true that `super.member` is allowed exactly when `d.member` is allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it true that the set of members (methods or fields) of `C` and its superclasses that you can access for `this` is exactly the same as the set of members you can access for `c`?

Yes. The access modifiers work on class level and not object level.

> Does it work for `super`?

Yes, `d.member` is allowed if and only if `super.member` is allowed.